# Brainf**k to Ruby converter, written in Ruby -- v1.0

Tags: ruby, converting, brainfuck

I've seen a lot of Brainf**k interpreters in various languages. I decided that actually interpreting Brainf**k is too hard, so instead of that, I wrote a 'compiler' in Ruby that directly transcribes BF to Ruby code. This is Version 1.0, and I'm looking for any tips on how to make it more efficient.

There are a few things that really bug me:

1. `replacements` feels like it's messed up somehow, but I can't put my finger on how.
2. `$stdin.readbyte` feels entirely too long, but I can't find an alternative that's shorter.
3. Should I be using `$stdin` at all?

```
input_file = $ARGV[0]
output_file = $ARGV[1]
start = <<-END.gsub(/[ \t]*\|/, '')
  |# Automatically generated by bf_to_ruby.rb
  |# Source available at GitHub
  |data = Hash.new(0)
  |pointer = 0
END

replacements = [
    { replacing: '+', replacement: 'data[pointer] += 1'              },
    { replacing: '-', replacement: 'data[pointer] -= 1'              },
    { replacing: '>', replacement: 'pointer += 1'                    },
    { replacing: '<', replacement: 'pointer -= 1'                    },
    { replacing: '.', replacement: 'putc data[pointer]'              },
    { replacing: ',', replacement: 'data[pointer] = $stdin.readbyte' },
    { replacing: '[', replacement: 'until data[pointer] == 0'        },
    { replacing: ']', replacement: 'end'                             },
]

output = open(output_file, File::CREAT | File::WRONLY)
output.puts(start)

open(input_file, File::RDONLY) do |input|
  input.each_char do |char|
    replacements.each do |data|
      if data[:replacing] == char
        output.puts(data[:replacement])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

#### Demo

Input:

> ```
> ++++++++[>++++[>++>+++>+++>+<<<<-]>+>+>->>+[<]<-]>>.>---.+++++++..+++.>>.<-.<.+++.------.--------.>>+.>++.
> ```

Output:

> ```
> # Automatically generated by bf_to_ruby.rb
> # Source available at GitHub
> data = Hash.new(0)
> pointer = 0
> data[pointer] += 1
> data[pointer] += 1
> data[pointer] += 1
> data[pointer] += 1
> data[pointer] += 1
> data[pointer] += 1
> data[pointer] += 1
> data[pointer] += 1
> until data[pointer] == 0
> pointer += 1
> data[pointer] += 1
> data[pointer] += 1
> data[pointer] += 1
> data[pointer] += 1
> until data[pointer] == 0
> pointer += 1
> data[pointer] += 1
> data[pointer] += 1
> pointer += 1
> data[pointer] += 1
> data[pointer] += 1
> data[pointer] += 1
> pointer += 1
> data[pointer] += 1
> data[pointer] += 1
> data[pointer] += 1
> pointer += 1
> data[pointer] += 1
> pointer -= 1
> pointer -= 1
> pointer -= 1
> pointer -= 1
> data[pointer] -= 1
> end
> pointer += 1
> data[pointer] += 1
> pointer += 1
> data[pointer] += 1
> pointer += 1
> data[pointer] -= 1
> pointer += 1
> pointer += 1
> data[pointer] += 1
> until data[pointer] == 0
> pointer -= 1
> end
> pointer -= 1
> data[pointer] -= 1
> end
> pointer += 1
> pointer += 1
> $stdout.putc data[pointer]
> pointer += 1
> data[pointer] -= 1
> data[pointer] -= 1
> data[pointer] -= 1
> $stdout.putc data[pointer]
> data[pointer] += 1
> data[pointer] += 1
> data[pointer] += 1
> data[pointer] += 1
> data[pointer] += 1
> data[pointer] += 1
> data[pointer] += 1
> $stdout.putc data[pointer]
> $stdout.putc data[pointer]
> data[pointer] += 1
> data[pointer] += 1
> data[pointer] += 1
> $stdout.putc data[pointer]
> pointer += 1
> pointer += 1
> $stdout.putc data[pointer]
> pointer -= 1
> data[pointer] -= 1
> $stdout.putc data[pointer]
> pointer -= 1
> $stdout.putc data[pointer]
> data[pointer] += 1
> data[pointer] += 1
> data[pointer] += 1
> $stdout.putc data[pointer]
> data[pointer] -= 1
> data[pointer] -= 1
> data[pointer] -= 1
> data[pointer] -= 1
> data[pointer] -= 1
> data[pointer] -= 1
> $stdout.putc data[pointer]
> data[pointer] -= 1
> data[pointer] -= 1
> data[pointer] -= 1
> data[pointer] -= 1
> data[pointer] -= 1
> data[pointer] -= 1
> data[pointer] -= 1
> data[pointer] -= 1
> $stdout.putc data[pointer]
> pointer += 1
> pointer += 1
> data[pointer] += 1
> $stdout.putc data[pointer]
> pointer += 1
> data[pointer] += 1
> data[pointer] += 1
> $stdout.putc data[pointer]
> ```

Both, when run, output:

> ```
> Hello World!
> ```

Comment: I'm always amazed by the ways people find spend their time. Of course, I once wrote a language. I made the comment character `$$` because I knew I would never make any money with the thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should open the input file before the output file, so that if the input file is unreadable, no file is created at all.  File opening should be done using blocks for automatic closure and cleanup.

This is too complicated:

> ```
> replacements.each do |data|
>   if data[:replacing] == char
>     output.puts(data[:replacement])
>   end
> end
> ```

`replacements` would be better as a `Hash`:

```
replacements = {
    '+' => 'data[pointer] += 1',
    '-' => 'data[pointer] -= 1',
    '>' => 'pointer += 1',
    '<' => 'pointer -= 1',
    '.' => 'putc data[pointer]',
    ',' => 'data[pointer] = $stdin.readbyte',
    '[' => 'until data[pointer] == 0',
    ']' => 'end',
}

open(input_file, File::RDONLY) do |input|
  open(output_file, File::CREAT | File::WRONLY) do |output|
    output.puts(start)
    output.puts(input.each_char.map { |c| replacements[c] }.compact.join("\n"))
  end
end
```

One big `puts` should be faster than many indivual `puts`.

Comment: "_One big puts should be faster than many indivual puts._" Yes, but that requires a lot more memory, so I intentionally _didn't_ do that. In retrospect, I probably should have commented, but it doesn't matter much.

Comment: I doubt you'll come close to hitting your memory limit.

Comment: Fair enough. It still bugs me, though.

Comment: Could I ask you two merge your answers into one? I'd like to accept both, since both helped greatly and v2 is about to come out, but unfortunately I can't.

Comment: This answer addresses the Ruby code; the other discusses the generated Brainfuck code. They even present different approaches to performing the translation. Since the answers are independent, I'd prefer to keep them separate.

Comment: Oh, I see. Fair enough.

Answer (score 6):

In Brainfuck, there are often long strings of `-`, `+`, `<`, and `>` commands.  Your generated code could be made more efficient by coalescing these commands.

In a common dialect of Brainfuck, data values wrap modulo 256.

Using `Hash.new(0)` to represent the memory is an interesting trick to present the illusion of infinite memory preinitialized to 0.  I would personally prefer to use an array, which should be more compact and doesn't require hashing.

It would be a good idea to include a shebang line in the output.

```
START = <<-END.gsub(/[ \t]*\|/, '')
  |#!/usr/bin/env ruby
  |# Automatically generated by bf_to_ruby.rb
  |# Source available at GitHub
  |class Mem < Array
  |  def [](i); self.fetch(i, 0); end
  |  def []=(i, val); super(i, val < 0 ? val += 256 : val); end
  |end
  |data = Mem.new
  |pointer = 0
END

def compile(bf)
  regex = /([-+][^<>.,\[\]]*) | # Run of - or +
           ([<>][^-+.,\[\]]*) | # Run of < or >
           ([,.\[\]])         | # Other significant characters
           ./mx
  bf.gsub(regex) do |match|
    if $1
      "data[pointer] += #{(match.count('+') - match.count('-')) % 256}\n"
    elsif $2
      "pointer += #{match.count('>') - match.count('<')}\n"
    elsif match == '.'
      "putc data[pointer]\n"
    elsif match == ','
      "data[pointer] = $stdin.readbyte\n"
    elsif match == '['
      "until data[pointer] == 0\n"
    elsif match == ']'
      "end\n"
    end
  end
end

input_file, output_file = ARGV[0..1]
bf = IO.read(input_file)
open(output_file, File::CREAT | File::WRONLY) do |output|
  output.puts(START)
  output.puts(compile(bf))
end
```