# Brainf**k to Ruby converter -- v2

Tags: ruby, converting, brainfuck

[Previous iteration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/94489/).

You know, I think this is the fastest I've ever pushed out an update to *anything*. This is Version 2 of my Brainf**k to Ruby converter, and the generated code looks... Well, like Brainf**k, converted directly to Ruby, with no attempt at making it more readable.

I'm looking for any tips on making things more idiomatic, both in the generator and generated code. The nest `if`/`case`s really bug me, but I'm not quite sure how to get rid of them, especially since just two characters are blindly replaced. I'd also like advice on making it run faster.

#### `bf_to_ruby.rb`

```
input_file, output_file = ARGV
code = IO.read(input_file).tr('^+-<>.,[]', '')

open(output_file, File::CREAT | File::WRONLY) do |output|
  output.puts <<-END.gsub(/^[ \t]*\||\s*#@.*$/, '')
    |#!/usr/bin/env ruby
    |class Mem < Hash #@ `Hash` because it's more memory-efficient and allows negative values.
    |  def initialize; super(0); end
    |  def []=(i, val); super(i, val & 255); end
    |end
    |data = Mem.new
    |pointer = 0
  END
  indent_level = 0
  code.scan(/(\++)|(\-+)|(<+)|(>+)|([.,\[\]])/)
      .map do |string|
        if string[0]
          next "#{'  ' * indent_level}data[pointer] += #{string[0].length}"
        elsif string[1]
          next "#{'  ' * indent_level}data[pointer] -= #{string[1].length}"
        elsif string[2]
          next "#{'  ' * indent_level}pointer -= #{string[2].length}"
        elsif string[3]
          next "#{'  ' * indent_level}pointer += #{string[3].length}"
        elsif string[4]
          case string[4]
            when '['
              ret = "#{'  ' * indent_level}until data[pointer] == 0"
              indent_level += 1
              next ret #Split it so that it's clear that indent is increased *after* the line
            when ']'
              indent_level -= 1
              next "#{'  ' * indent_level}end"
            when ','
              next "#{'  ' * indent_level}data[pointer] = $stdin.readbyte"
            when '.'
              next "#{'  ' * indent_level}putc data[pointer]"
          end
        end
      end.each { |line| output.puts(line) }
end
```

#### Demo

Input:

> ```
> ++++++++[>++++[>++>+++>+++>+<<<<-]>+>+>->>+[<]<-]>>.>---.+++++++..+++.>>.<-.<.+++.------.--------.>>+.>++.
> ```

Output:

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env ruby
> class Mem < Hash
>   def initialize; super(0); end
>   def []=(i, val); super(i, val & 255); end
> end
> data = Mem.new
> pointer = 0
> data[pointer] += 8
> until data[pointer] == 0
>   pointer += 1
>   data[pointer] += 4
>   until data[pointer] == 0
>     pointer += 1
>     data[pointer] += 2
>     pointer += 1
>     data[pointer] += 3
>     pointer += 1
>     data[pointer] += 3
>     pointer += 1
>     data[pointer] += 1
>     pointer -= 4
>     data[pointer] -= 1
>   end
>   pointer += 1
>   data[pointer] += 1
>   pointer += 1
>   data[pointer] += 1
>   pointer += 1
>   data[pointer] -= 1
>   pointer += 2
>   data[pointer] += 1
>   until data[pointer] == 0
>     pointer -= 1
>   end
>   pointer -= 1
>   data[pointer] -= 1
> end
> pointer += 2
> putc data[pointer]
> pointer += 1
> data[pointer] -= 3
> putc data[pointer]
> data[pointer] += 7
> putc data[pointer]
> putc data[pointer]
> data[pointer] += 3
> putc data[pointer]
> pointer += 2
> putc data[pointer]
> pointer -= 1
> data[pointer] -= 1
> putc data[pointer]
> pointer -= 1
> putc data[pointer]
> data[pointer] += 3
> putc data[pointer]
> data[pointer] -= 6
> putc data[pointer]
> data[pointer] -= 8
> putc data[pointer]
> pointer += 2
> data[pointer] += 1
> putc data[pointer]
> pointer += 1
> data[pointer] += 2
> putc data[pointer]
> ```

You'll notice that the generated code is nearly the same as the last version's generated code, but with a lot of duplicate lines merged and indenting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're correct that nesting a `case` in an `elsif` ladder is a bit clunky here, but the two things that jump out at me as making the code difficult to comprehend are: 1) we have to know everything that's going on with the `Regexp` passed to `scan()` in order to figure out the intent of the `if` clauses, and 2) the variable `string` is not a `String`, but an `Array`.

You can remove the capture groups from your `Regexp` to just get an `Array` of `String`s back from `scan()` (instead of an `Array` of `Array`s of `String`s), and figure out what exactly was matched by looking at the strings themselves - which means you don't need a nested `case` anymore, and makes it a little more obvious what `scan()` is doing without having to actually parse its argument.

Like this:

```
# example.rb
code = '--+++.,,'
code.scan(/\++|\-+|[.,]/).map { |str|
  case str[0]
  when '+'
    "Plus signs: #{str.length}"
  when '-'
    "Minus signs: #{str.length}"
  when '.'
    'Dot!'
  when ','
    'Comma!'
  end
}.each {|ll| puts ll}
```

Produces:

```
$ ruby example.rb 
Minus signs: 2
Plus signs: 3
Dot!
Comma!
Comma!
```